# script src link not found by chrome

Tags: javascript, html, express

so when I tried to link a JS file on an HTML file by script src
I get an error by chrome:
[image]

I supposed this is because chrome does not find my JS file. I linked it on the bottom of the body this way:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/registro.js"></script>
```

And when I click the error on Chrome it highlights exactly that line:
[image]

This is part of my app.js:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname + '/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/public')));
app.use(session({
  secret: 'kitten',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  proxy: true
}));
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
```

My folder structure is:

```
Proyect
   |
  App.js
   |
   +--Views
   |      |
   |  register.ejs
   |      |
   |  login.ejs
   |      |
   |      +--js
   |          |
   |          +--registro.js
   |          +--login.js
   | 
All my other folders, routes, controllers
```

Comment: try removing the dot `.` at the begginning of the address

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: What is your folder structure ?

Comment: I edited the folder structure into the question. Hope it is understandable. It is the first time i did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static files are served up with the `static` module.

You are using the `static` module.

Your `js` directory **isn't** in the path that you configured the `static` module to look in.

Comment: So how should I configure it?

Comment: Put the static JS files in the public directory where you told Express to look for them! … and remove the `.` from the front of the URL because you didn't anchor the static module to the `/users/` route.

Comment: app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/js')));      Like this is fine?

Comment: No. Don't change where you are looking. **Move the JS directory**.

Comment: Done! Thank you so much!